# I want to encode the column values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to encode the column values in pandas dataframe, such as the all the letters should be converted to a single letter(eg., `'vault'` to `'NNNNN'` , `'Nan123'` to `'NNNDDD'`).

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
df['TransDetails'] = df['TransDetails'].str.replace('A', 'N')
```

My data:

```
    TransDetails
0   NEFT-PUNB0315500-JITENDER SING
1   NEFT-UTIB0CCH274-VIRENDER KUMA
2   NEFT-UTIB0CCH274-SUNITA DEVI
3   NEFT-PUNB0315500-AMLASH KUMAR
4   NEFT-PUNB0109800-FARIDUDDEN
5   NEFT-PUNB0109800-IDREESH
6   NEFT-PUNB0315500-BUDDHU
7   NEFT-UTIB0CCH274-SAKIL AHAMAD
8   NEFT-UTIB0CCH274-NAIM AHAMAD
9   NEFT-UTIB0CCH274-SALIM AHAMAD
10  NEFT-UTIB0CCH274-NADIM AHAMAD
```

How can I convert all the column values in such codes? Thanks in advance

Comment: All column values? OR just dtype='object'? Probably you just want to use a simple `.apply()` with `axis=1`

Comment: yes all column values. i tried .apply() but it replaces one character a time. i want something that can change all the letters to a single letter

Comment: Well in that case you can probably use df.replace().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use [`df.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html). You would avoid changing numeric columns this way.

```
df.replace('[A-Za-z]','N', regex=True).replace('\d','D', regex=True)
```

Full example with a numeric column called `D`, A non-numeric called `N` and `TransDetails`.

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
D,N,TransDetails
1,ABC,NEFT-PUNB0315500-JITENDER SING
1,123,NEFT-UTIB0CCH274-VIRENDER KUMA
1,123,NEFT-UTIB0CCH274-SUNITA DEVI
1,123,NEFT-PUNB0315500-AMLASH KUMAR
1,123,NEFT-PUNB0109800-FARIDUDDEN
1,123,NEFT-PUNB0109800-IDREESH
1,123,NEFT-PUNB0315500-BUDDHU
1,123,NEFT-UTIB0CCH274-SAKIL AHAMAD
1,123,NEFT-UTIB0CCH274-NAIM AHAMAD
1,123,NEFT-UTIB0CCH274-SALIM AHAMAD
1,123,NEFT-UTIB0CCH274-NADIM AHAMAD'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(data) # or 'path/to/csv'
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj)
df = df.replace('[A-Za-z]','N', regex=True).replace('\d','D', regex=True)
print(df)
```

Returns:

```
    D    N                    TransDetails
0   1  NNN  NNNN-NNNNDDDDDDD-NNNNNNNN NNNN
1   1  DDD  NNNN-NNNNDNNNDDD-NNNNNNNN NNNN
2   1  DDD    NNNN-NNNNDNNNDDD-NNNNNN NNNN
3   1  DDD   NNNN-NNNNDDDDDDD-NNNNNN NNNNN
4   1  DDD     NNNN-NNNNDDDDDDD-NNNNNNNNNN
5   1  DDD        NNNN-NNNNDDDDDDD-NNNNNNN
6   1  DDD         NNNN-NNNNDDDDDDD-NNNNNN
7   1  DDD   NNNN-NNNNDNNNDDD-NNNNN NNNNNN
8   1  DDD    NNNN-NNNNDNNNDDD-NNNN NNNNNN
9   1  DDD   NNNN-NNNNDNNNDDD-NNNNN NNNNNN
10  1  DDD   NNNN-NNNNDNNNDDD-NNNNN NNNNNN
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked well. Can i directly use it on a csv?

Comment: @nehaj You are welcome. Happy programming. You can change fileobj to path to csv.

Comment: Thanks a ton Buddy!! Saved me big time.

Comment: Hi! How can I convert the Exponential values in csv file? I don't want that plus(+) sign to appear in the conversion

Comment: @nehaj Hey! Sorry what (+) signs are you referring to? I think you should open a new question with some data! :)

Comment: 6.12E+11 Converts to D.DDN+DD.
But i want the actual value without exponential format.

Comment: @nehaj Ok is that a column? In that case you should try to to: `df['col'] = pd.to_numeric(df['col']).astype(str)` first. And if not we would have to run a specfic regex pattern for it first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to handle the replacement.

```
df['TransDetails'] = df['TransDetails'].str.replace('[A-Za-z]', 'N')
df['TransDetails'] = df['TransDetails'].str.replace('\d', 'D')

df
# returns:
                      TransDetails
0   NNNN-NNNNDDDDDDD-NNNNNNNN NNNN
1   NNNN-NNNNDNNNDDD-NNNNNNNN NNNN
2     NNNN-NNNNDNNNDDD-NNNNNN NNNN
3    NNNN-NNNNDDDDDDD-NNNNNN NNNNN
4      NNNN-NNNNDDDDDDD-NNNNNNNNNN
5         NNNN-NNNNDDDDDDD-NNNNNNN
6          NNNN-NNNNDDDDDDD-NNNNNN
7    NNNN-NNNNDNNNDDD-NNNNN NNNNNN
8     NNNN-NNNNDNNNDDD-NNNN NNNNNN
9    NNNN-NNNNDNNNDDD-NNNNN NNNNNN
10   NNNN-NNNNDNNNDDD-NNNNN NNNNNN
```

Comment: hey thanks, it did work for all the letters, but not the digits. It changed all the numbers to N too